# Representing and Extracting Properties of a System Product Breakdown Structure (a Directed Acyclic Graph)

Tags: graphs-and-networks, associations

I am trying to analyze products using a product breakdown structure (PBS), which is a directed acyclic graph (DAG) that reflects a decomposition of the product into subproducts, sub-sub-products, and so on.  For example, if my product is a spacecraft, I can decompose the spacecraft into a (vehicular) bus, and one or more payloads.  The bus and payloads can in turn be thought of as products also, that are comprised of sub-elements.  And so on.  One approach for representing such a PBS can be done in Mathematica like this:

```
sc = <|"bus" -> "craft" , "Payload1" -> "craft", 
  "Payload2" -> "craft", "PayComp" -> "Payload1", 
  "Cam1" -> "PayComp", "Cam2" -> "PayComp", "power" -> "bus", 
  "computer" -> "bus", "struct" -> "bus" , "guidance" -> "bus" , 
  "radio" -> "bus", "solar" -> "power", "battery" -> "power"|>
```

And the product representation can be visually depicted with a TreePlot:

```
TreePlot[Normal[sc], ImageSize -> 400, DirectedEdges -> True, 
     VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image: PBS of a spacecraft]

I would like to bind properties, simple and complex, to each node of the PBS.  A simple example is mass.  A more complex example might be a power consumption profile, which might itself be a tree structure (reflect the amount of electrical power required when a component is placed in one of many different states, and the state of one node defines the state of nodes below it in the hierarchy).

Is there a simple approach for adding "Mass" to each node, but more importantly to be able to add a variety of properties, since I know there are ways to represent weights for nodes and edges in graph structures.  I need to have many different properties.  I know there is a data set approach that even allows recursion / hierarchy, but I do not know how to recurse the query of properties throughout a hierarchy.  For example, I would like to be able to arrive at a total mass of a product, which is of course the sum of the mass of its parts.  A more complex calculation might be power consumption, where efficiency losses must be accounted for (in this case the power of a node is more than the sum of the power of the elements).

Comment: Interesting. I'm investigating into exactly these kind of questions. I'm thinking of using custom properties (AnnotationValue) in the vertexes and edges combined with custom entity stores. I also suggest to use IGraph package.

Comment: Yes, you can associate custom properties with vertices, using `Property` (recently renamed `Annotation`). Have you tried these functions?

Comment: I am going to explore this a bit more and report back.  Thank you.